# Efficient way to replicate "confetti" effect for repeated use

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, illustrator-effects

I have several "confetti" images that I want to take the design and create a method so I can replicate it as a fill I can apply to shapes/outlines.

Here's an example of the source image.

[image]

I'm not set on Illustrator or Photoshop, pretty much whatever I can use to do this efficiently.

I'm trying to avoid manually cutting out each circle.

---

### Issues/Ideas

The issue is setting-up the initial pattern so it has layering and the color-variation.

I've looked into some Illustrator scripts to [randomize fill color](http://vectorboom.com/load/freebies/freescripts/randomswatchesfill/22-1-0-167) and [randomize ordering](http://vectorboom.com/load/freebies/freescripts/randomorder/22-1-0-253) but this means that I'd have to extract each color circle and save it as a symbol for it to be of use.

I was considering using [Jongware's CircleFill script](http://www.jongware.com/binaries/CircleFill.zip) to generate circles and then apply styles but then there is the issue of ordering and layering plus color randomness to account for.

I have access to Astute plugins now but I'm VERY new to learning them so I'm not sure if any of them can help me.

---

### UPDATES

1. I've started tinkering with "seed pods" of circles that I apply a random transform each command to. My issue now is that I have to create a lot of variations. Is there a more efficient way to create these and then splice them all together?

Comment: I honestly am not sure there's anything which will help, other than symbols and scripts.

Comment: Perfect example of a *good* "how do I do a thing" question

Comment: @LateralTerminal Is it though? I'm not asking how, I have several ideas how, I'm asking for efficient methods. If you read my question I state how I've gone through several scripts and how I "could" implement them and state the drawbacks I'm trying to work around.

Comment: @LateralTerminal Additionally I have not stated that I'm looking for something without trying anything. I'm looking for OPTIMIZATION. Yes there are ways to do the design manually but I'm looking for a replicable, efficient method.

Comment: What's wrong with how to do a thing? If I didn't ask a bunch of those throughout the years I wouldn't have been able to give a bunch of my own answers to people today...

Comment: @Ovaryraptor I wasn't being sarcastic at all. I think this is a good example. I guess you didn't see all the discussion going on in meta

Comment: @Silly-V Nothing is wrong with asking. It's about the amount of effort put in. There's a big discussion going on here https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/what-to-do-with-tutorial-requests-part-ii

Comment: @LateralTerminal I did, I don't think that my post fits that at all. Those discussions are specifically relating to newer users and more importantly low-quality hit-and-run posts. I appreciate your vigilance but do you really think that this fits that?

Comment: @Ovaryraptor I think your post is a good example for new users to see how they should format their question yes.

Comment: @LateralTerminal I took the liberty to add emphasis to your first comment, to underscore that you are giving positive feedback. Feel free to re-edit, and take into account the site is still suffering from a problem where [italic and bold don't display in all browsers](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/bold-and-italic-no-longer-possible-to-make).

Comment: Funny how the brain works.. I skipped right over the word "good", only now seeing it. lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use raster images in various layers and colors along with the Illustrator "Object Mosaic" feature. Once you have your object turned into many colorized squares by Illustrator automatically, you can ungroup everything and apply a rounded corner effect or appearance to make each square into a circle. Also you can use the convert-to-shape or various fill transforms in the appearance palette to effectively turn each little square into virtually any shape you desire by using graphic styles.

But, work will not be over yet as there's the randomization /swarming to account for. In order to accomplish this you can once again act on the ungrouped individual selected items via the Transform Each command. Transform Each has a 'randomize' checkbox and can help you randomize x,y change in position, vertical and horizontal scaling and rotation. While xy changes are obvious, rotation may be helpful if you choose to incorporate gradients or brushes or patterns upon your circles, this way the round shape can be rotated and provide more variety with the contents of the circles having a visual distinction such as what you can barely see in your sample image where a pale line runs through the circles at different angles.

And here's the stacking order snippet.

```
#target illustrator
function test(){
    function shuffle(a) {
      var j, x, i;
      for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
      }
    };
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var s = doc.selection;
    var arr = [], thisItem;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        thisItem = s[i];
        arr.push(thisItem);
    }
    shuffle(arr);
    doc.selection = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        thisItem = arr[i];
        thisItem.move(doc.layers[0], ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
    }
};
test();
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I looked into using the Transform each to create "seed pods" of circles and then additionally transform each of those. But then I run into the issue of spacing and having to manually make several dozen "pods".

Comment: Check out the new screenshot, it was made using my conceptual technique. Isn't it close to what you want? The cool thing is, these 'swarming' dots are actually square rectangle shapes, all stacked on top of each other like grid work. What makes them round and random is effects: convert to shape (ellipse) as well as Transform effect which is NOT on a group but on individually grouped items.

Comment: *Correction: "which is NOT on a group but on individually grouped items." is actually "which is NOT on a group but on individually selected ungrouped items."

Comment: And to optimize or automate, you can try to mess around with Actions. It's possible to record the Object Mosaic command, deselect, selection of white and selection of same fill-color to leave your rectangle shapes sans white ones which is what it creates when you do the mosaic. After that, you can have your action apply your named graphic style which you'd have pre-created. Thus your work could be reduced to using a brush to make your colored paths, then rasterizing and then running your automation routine. And, let us not forget that after all, you can change the effect settings too.

Comment: As for randomizing stacking order, yea you can ask for someone to create a quick script snippet for you. I think it wouldn't take so long. And, if you posses such a snippet then you can put it into your Actions - thankfully Adobe fixed the action thing so that it remembers your scripts you inserted.

Comment: Okay.. fine, it might as well be me. New update on answer..

Comment: What were your object mosaic settings like? I'm not really familiar with them and how they interact.

Comment: Additionally, do you think that there is a way to be able to convert every circle/square to a symbol? This method works great for complex shapes but not so great when I have a large volume to fill.

Comment: The object mosaic settings I used, I do not remember, but I tried a couple different ways with different height/width settings to get the visual result I wanted. And I'm not sure about the 2nd question. If you just have a solid shape to fill with these, and would want each thing to be a symbol, you can ask someone to make a script that replaces the items with symbol instances or something.